# Custom query string in Woocommerce external / affiliate product URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, external, product

I wonder if you guys can help. I do not know php very well.

I would like to add the same extra string on every external product url. The extra string would be like "?prodid=12345" so I do not want to overide the url just add to it. Would this be possible? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with the following hooked function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'custom_product_add_to_cart_url', 20, 2 );
function custom_product_add_to_cart_url( $add_to_cart_url, $product ){
    if( $product->is_type('external') )
        $add_to_cart_url .= '?prodid=' . $product->get_id();

    return $add_to_cart_url;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

> You can change in the code `$product->get_id();` by a static value or any other dynamic value of your choice.

Comment: Done. Thanks again